# OnsenUI: How to show a map/image above an ons-list

Tags: javascript

I'm using the sliding-menu-template as a starting point.

On the first page I try to show a Map at the top and below a ons-list. What I try to accomplish is, that:

- the list starts *below* the map
- if the users swipes vertically, the list should scroll, but the map should stay fixed.

If I use standard elements (div, ul, li, etc...) everything is fine, but it seems ons-list always occupies the whole page (a .fullscreen class is added to the list).

What am I doing wrong? How can I avoid a list being full-screen? (documentation is not helpful at all, here)

thx
andy

Comment: Since I can't answer here (because this stupid 'SO' 'no longer accepts answers from my account'), I'm posting the solution in the comment:

<ons-page ng-controller="MapCtrl">
      <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 200px"></div>
      <ons-list style="position: relative; height: 100%; display: block;">
         <ons-list-item class="topcoat-list__item__line-height">item 1</ons-list-item>
         <ons-list-item class="topcoat-list__item__line-height">item 2</ons-list-item>
     </ons-list>
</ons-page>

Comment: Looks bad: Goodbye... ;/

Answer (score 0):

it's discussed in Onsen UI Github issue.

https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/40